# SharePoint 2010 Reassign Tasks that were created using Collect Data from User in Workflow

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow

I have a OOTB SharePoint 2010 Workflow that has a few different "collect data from user" steps to accomplish a process flow on infopath forms. The client would like to be able to reassign the task that is created and have it go back to the correct step in the workflow.

Anyone have any suggestion on how to go about accomplishing this? Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I ended up doing was redoing the workflow and instead of using the "Collect data from user" action I used "Create custom task process" action, which gives the reassignment feature.

Thx.

Comment: Juan i am also trying to creating a workflow where user sends request to 2 users sequentially. First the approval goes to coordinator, then supervisor at last manager. On those three steps if Approvers shoudl have permission to send the form back for review. which will send email to created by. After making changes it needs to come back to the approver again to move forward. DO you have nay idea how this can be achieved.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you open the approval WF in SharePoint Designer there will be a choice in settings called Reassignment. Just check that item and you should be ready to go.

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately I am not using the standard Approval action but I am using the Collect Data from User action which does not have the options as in the screenshot.  Am I stuck re-doing the workflow and changing from Collect Data to standard approval process?

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at this [video](http://bit.ly/OFyFRp), I am sure this is gonna help you for collecting data from users.